# Regex not working way it should with .replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I am novice to jQuery but I got a simple script which is supposed to strip integers from a string but it seems to only strip the first 2 digits?

Ideas?

```js
var strValue = "5321 Test";

var regex = /([0-9])/;

strValue = strValue.replace(regex,'');

alert(strValue);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use global regex modifier :

```
/[0-9]/g
```

**`g`**: *global*. All matches (don't return on first match).

Or you could add `+` to your regex, to target all the integers not only the first :

```
/([0-9]+)/;
```

**`0-9`**: A single character in the range between 0 and 9.

**`+`**: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

Or also using `\d+`.

**`d`**: match a digit [0-9].

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var strValue = "5321 Test";

var regex = /([0-9])/g;

strValue = strValue.replace(regex,'');

alert(strValue);
```

Comment: Or use the global regex modifier: `/[0-9]/g`

Comment: Or, just `\d+` if you want to keep it short :P

Comment: Adding a plus behind it only matches the first group of digits. So if you would have "123 test 123" it would become " test 123"

Answer (score 3):

You should add a g after your regex, that means that it has to replace all the occurrences, not just the first one. So your code would be:

```
var strValue = "5321 Test";
var regex = /([0-9])/g;
strValue = strValue.replace(regex,'');
alert(strValue);
```